# How to add directory to existing Data container in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have made a data container in Docker with the directory /tmp:
sudo docker create -v /tmp --name datacontainer ubuntu

I will add another directory to this existing data container like /opt.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a [new data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#adding-a-data-volume) to an existing (created or running) container.

With docker 1.9+, you would use instead [docker volume create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/):

```
docker volume create --name my-tmp
docker volume create --name my-opt
```

Then you can mount those volumes to any container you want (when you run those containers, not when they are already running)

```
docker run -d -P \
  -v my-tmp:/tmp \
  -v my-opt:/opt \
  --name mycontainer myimage
```